# Getting couldn't send attachment error while attaching images with Gmail app

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-sharing, android-fileprovider

I have a file path of images which was taken from the Gallery and I am adding each file path in to ArrayList. Everything works fine and even I could see the attachments in Gmail. But once if I try to send the images. I am getting couldn't send attachments error. Please help me to resolve this issue. I am completely stuck up with the solutions. Thanks in advance.

The path of a image is something like `/storage/emulated/0/myfolder/1433917106851_fact_2.jpg`

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
                intent.setType("image/jpeg"); /* This example is sharing jpeg images. */
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mShareImages);  //<=== This is the arraylist of images path. 
                startActivity(intent);
```

Note: mShareImages is a `ArrayList<Uri>`. I am converting `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Uri>` by using

```
Uri uri = Uri.Parse(string);
```

Finally adding this uri object into ArrayList by

```
mShareImages.add(uri);
```

Comment: I got this error. It was because the path of one of my file wasn't right, so gmail wasn't able to read/attach the file and showed "Couldn't send attachment".

Answer (score 0):

You should put list of the Uri into intent extras, not list of String

Comment: s I am doing the same. Check my edited question

Answer (score 0):

mShareImages needs to be a ArrayList of type Uri and not String.